# I2C communication between Arduino Due and Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, i2c, arduino-due, wire-library

I'm trying to communicate between two Arduino Due and Nano. Nano as Master and Due as a slave. As given in the library description [Wire Lib](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterReader)

When the master request for data from the slave, first it goes to Request ISR. `Wire.onRequest(requestEvent)`    But when compile the program for Arduino Due I get following errors.

```
In file included from C:\Users\\Slave_Test3.ino:14:0:


C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\1.6.11\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.h:59:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void TwoWire::onRequest(void (*)())' [-fpermissive]



 void onRequest(void(*)(void));

       ^
```

But If I change from Arduino Due to any other board this error does not come.

Thank you

Comment: It looks like a problem with the `Wire` lib that the Due BSP includes.

Answer (score 1):

Dead easy !!
(Well only because I had a `-fpermissive` yesterday :) )

You are trying to implicitly cast, and you can't do that with modern GCC versions (quite rightly).

So you need to explicitly cast the first parameter to void*.

Because this is in a "core" library for the Due I would get the latest version of the board package and see if it goes away.  You can turn the check off, but you will need to google on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Yes, I have the latest version of the board package. Still, I'm getting those errors. Can please elaborate your last suggestion I am new to this.

Comment: Not really because I can't see the code that has the problem.

Comment: I have written the same come as given [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterReader) .

Comment: That link won't help.  This "error" is not in your code, its in Wire.h as per your original post